# Reading language from source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I would like to use lightbox in multi-language (en, ru, lt) site, so i need to translate lightbox.
To set correct parameters to lightbox i need to read language witch is defined in:

```
    <body>
        <div id="main">

    <div id="logo"> 
        <a href="/en/" ...
```

So if i'm in another language logo link would be that language code. I have this .js code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.object').lightBox({
        txtOf: 'translation',
        txtImage: 'another_translation'
    });
});
```

How i should alter JS to do the checking?

Comment: What do you mean by "checking"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    // Define language map
    var languageMap = {
      en: {txtOf: 'Something', txtImage: 'This is an image'},
      ru: {txtOf: 'что-то', txtImage: 'его является изображение'}
    };
    // Detect language from the logo images href attribute
    var re = new RegExp('/([^/]*)/*');
    var href = $('#logo a').eq(0).attr('href');
    var lang = 'en'; //English by default
    var match = re.exec(href);
    if (match !== null) {
        lang = match[1];
    }
    // initialize lightBox
    $('.object').lightBox({
        txtOf: languageMap[lang].txtOf,
        txtImage: languageMap[lang].txtImage
    });
})
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/JzPZP/ for a live example.

Also http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/JzPZP/1 will show you russian version

Comment: can you explain this line? var re = new RegExp('/([^/]*)/*');

Comment: @JackLeo sure, it's a regular expression to find and match anything that starts with a `/`, has one or more non-`/` characters and ends with another `/` (The trailing asterisk is a typo)

Comment: @JackLeo asterisk means, "last character, repeated zero or more times", i.e. `ba*` would match `ba` or `baaa` or `baaaaa` but also `b` because it's ''zero'' or more times

Comment: @JackLeo you can specify a character set in brackets like so `[a-zA-Z0-9]` this would match any letter from a-z, any capital letter A-Z or any number 0-9, if you add an asterisk after the bracket, it will match any word with zero or more letters belonging to that set. If the character set starts with a `^` character, it means, "any character except the following characters". So `[^+-]` would mean, match any character except plus and minus sign.

Comment: @JackLeo Regular braces `(` and `)` means, grab and remember what's inside them. So, finally, `/([^/]*)/` literary means, find and remember me a string that starts after a `/` character, has a number of characters other than `/`, and ends before another `/` character. So if you have a link like: "/en/images/logo.jpg" it will match words "en" and "images", but we're interested in the first match only, hence the `lang = match[1];`. If you are unfamiliar with regular expressions, check http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

I modified lightbox.js the get control of itself and its options:

```
//(function () {
//    var $, Lightbox, LightboxOptions;
//    $ = jQuery;
    var Lightbox, LightboxOptions;
    LightboxOptions = (function () {
        [...]
    })();

    Lightbox = (function () {
        [...]
    })();
//    $(function () {
//        var lightbox, options;
//        options = new LightboxOptions;
//        return lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
//    });
//}).call(this);
```

On the other hand I have to call a little code snippet in every page I want the gallery instead of just adding de library in the head:

```
$(function () {
    var lightbox, options;
    options = new LightboxOptions;
    return lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
});
```

But now, I can change programatically the lightbox options without doing extra changes:
ASP.net:

```
$(function () {
    var lightbox, options;
    options = new LightboxOptions;
    options.labelImage = '<%=this.GetLocalResourceObject("Lightbox.options.labelImage").ToString() %>';
    options.labelOf = '<%=this.GetLocalResourceObject("Lightbox.options.labelOf").ToString() %>';
    return lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
});
```

PHP:

```
$(function () {
    var lightbox, options;
    options = new LightboxOptions;
    options.labelImage = '<?php echo $dictionary["Lightbox_options_labelOf"]; ?>';
    options.labelOf = '<?php echo $dictionary["Lightbox.options.labelOf"]; ?>';
    return lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
});
```